# I tried installing Bagisto on a Pi, and I decided to uninstall it. Now, my PHPmyadmin doesn't work

Tags: terminal, phpmyadmin

I was trying to install bagisto, then I gave up and removed the folder from my var/www/html directory. After I had given a command when setting up Bagisto, my phpmyadmin won't let me access my dashboard. I think I have php 8.3 and it is on an Apache web server. I enter my login info and it says my web server isnt responding. Here is the error I am getting from phpmyadmin:

```html
Deprecation Notice in ./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40
 realpath(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($path) of type string is deprecated

Backtrace

./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Loader/FilesystemLoader.php#40: realpath(NULL)
./libraries/classes/Template.php#59: Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader->__construct(string '/var/www/html/phpmyadmin//templates/')
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#103: PhpMyAdmin\Template->__construct()
./libraries/classes/Theme.php#174: PhpMyAdmin\Theme->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#304: PhpMyAdmin\Theme::load(
string './themes/pmahomme',
string '/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/./themes/pmahomme/',
)
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#89: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->loadThemes()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#129: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager->__construct()
./libraries/classes/ThemeManager.php#397: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::getInstance()
./libraries/common.inc.php#315: PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager::initializeTheme()
./index.php#23: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
Deprecation Notice in ./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Node/Node.php#161
 Return type of Twig\Node\Node::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

Backtrace

./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/autoload.php#370: require(./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Node/Node.php)
{closure}(string 'Twig\\Node\\Node')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TwigFilter.php#150: class_exists(string 'Twig\\Node\\Node')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/autoload.php#370: require(./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TwigFilter.php)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Extension/CoreExtension.php#214: {closure}(string 'Twig\\TwigFilter')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#433: Twig\Extension\CoreExtension->getFilters()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#423: Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtension()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#243: Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtensions()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Environment.php#797: Twig\ExtensionSet->getFilter(string 'error')
49433f77d3462b2488dfef3699484854e3c55e4b348dae30482fadd1ce008731.php#63: Twig\Environment->getFilter(string 'error')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#405: __TwigTemplate_95dd0b99dd97a989e49170a5554a1e0ce6595b0346e92b70254c854745cea47e->doDisplay(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#378: Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#390: Twig\Template->display(array)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render(
array,
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Template.php#134: Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#141: PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(
string 'login/header',
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#268: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
./libraries/common.inc.php#365: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
./index.php#23: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
Deprecation Notice in ./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Node/Node.php#166
 Return type of Twig\Node\Node::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

Backtrace

./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/autoload.php#370: require(./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Node/Node.php)
{closure}(string 'Twig\\Node\\Node')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TwigFilter.php#150: class_exists(string 'Twig\\Node\\Node')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/autoload.php#370: require(./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TwigFilter.php)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Extension/CoreExtension.php#214: {closure}(string 'Twig\\TwigFilter')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#433: Twig\Extension\CoreExtension->getFilters()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#423: Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtension()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/ExtensionSet.php#243: Twig\ExtensionSet->initExtensions()
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Environment.php#797: Twig\ExtensionSet->getFilter(string 'error')
49433f77d3462b2488dfef3699484854e3c55e4b348dae30482fadd1ce008731.php#63: Twig\Environment->getFilter(string 'error')
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#405: __TwigTemplate_95dd0b99dd97a989e49170a5554a1e0ce6595b0346e92b70254c854745cea47e->doDisplay(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#378: Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling(
array,
array,
)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/Template.php#390: Twig\Template->display(array)
./../../../../../../../../usr/share/php/Twig/TemplateWrapper.php#45: Twig\Template->render(
array,
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Template.php#134: Twig\TemplateWrapper->render(array)
./libraries/classes/Plugins/Auth/AuthenticationCookie.php#141: PhpMyAdmin\Template->render(
string 'login/header',
array,
)
./libraries/classes/Plugins/AuthenticationPlugin.php#268: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Auth\AuthenticationCookie->showLoginForm()
./libraries/common.inc.php#365: PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\AuthenticationPlugin->authenticate()
./index.php#23: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
```